# inserts 'Array' into mysql table

Tags: php

i want to insert an array into a mysql table. The array is produced by script scanning all the links, converting into absolute links and then displaying them in an array. i decided to mysql_query the array into the table but now i am stuck. it only posts 'Array', instead of every row from the array into a different row. Any ideas??!

```
   <?php
 require_once('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');
 require_once('url_to_absolute/url_to_absolute.php');
   $connect = mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxx") or die('Couldn\'t connect to MySQL Server: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("xxxx", $connect ) or die('Couldn\'t Select the database: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));

  $links = Array();
  $URL = 'http://www.theqlick.com'; // change it for urls to grab  
  // grabs the urls from URL 
 $file  = file_get_html($URL);
 foreach ($file->find('a') as $theelement) {
  $links[] = url_to_absolute($URL, $theelement->href);
  } 
  print_r($links);
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO pages (url) VALUES ('$links[]')");
  mysql_close($connect);
```

Comment: create a new table 'url_id' 'link' to store each link, basic db normalisation you never want to store multiple discrete pieces of data in one field.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) with a separator that doesn't appear in the data (non-printable characters are usually a good bet, but sometimes various symbols work). Alternatively, you can let PHP [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) it for you, or even save it in [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode)d format.

If you are actually trying to insert multiple rows with one `$links` entry each, you should do:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pages (url) VALUES ('".implode("'),('",$links)."')");
```

Just make sure all the links are properly sanitised first!

Comment: only if count($links) > 0 :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could represent the array in JSON format and insert that into your database.  But really, a good database design should make the insertion of an array unnecessary.  Much better to have a separate column for each key in the array and just store the values instead of the actual array structure.

Comment: If you look at the original code it seems clear the OP wants to use bulk insert.

Answer (score 1):

Convert array to string?
It's the best option I think..

```
$ids = join(',',$links);  
$sql = "INSERT INTO pages (url) VALUES ('$ids')";
```

Comment: You need to add single quotes to the `$ids` string.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

```
$serialized = serialize( $yourArray );
// insert _$serialized_ into the DB
// and when retrieving it - unserialize()
$unserialized = unserialize( $retrievedValue );
```

Comment: If you look at the original code it seems clear the OP wants to use bulk insert.

Comment: @MikeBrant No challenge, but how is that clear? In the question he says *"I want to insert **an array** into a mysql table"* and not separate entries one by one. If he wanted to do that he could just include the INSERT statement in the foreach loop

Answer (score -1):

You need to iterate over the array and make an INSERT query for each element in turn.

Comment: If you look at the original code it seems clear the OP wants to use bulk insert.

Comment: @Mike: TIL SQL has bulk insert. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

if you want to store into the db a link each row, you should put the mysql_query("INSERT INTO pages (url) VALUES ('$link')"); inside the foreach cycle.

Otherwise use the implode method:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: If you look at the original code it seems clear the OP wants to use bulk insert.

Answer (score -1):

If you are only trying to insert one column try this. This prevents need to loop by building a proper `VALUES` string.

```
$value_string = "'" . implode("','", $links) . "'"; // makes string like 'url1','url2','url3'
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pages (url) VALUES ($value_string)");
```

Comment: `<a href="foo'); drop table pages; --">`